# Disable main mac screen to use secondary as main display

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors

My 27" iMac 2011 display has completely stopped working (blank with no backlight either). I have a second display set up already. However the imac screen is still setup as the main monitor, so all of the preferences windows open on that screen....which I can't see. Is there a way to disable the iMac screen completely so osX thinks that the secondary monitor is the only monitor? I don't have the tools to disconnect the imac screen via the hardware cables.

I tried opening system preferences and clicking around on the main screen blindly to drag the preferences window over to the second screen...but no luck.

Also, annoyingly, I turned off the feature that allows you to have the menu bar on all screens...so it's only on my imac screen.

Answer (score 0):

I can't show it 'live' because the mouse lets go when I try to snapshot, but you can drag the menu bar to your secondary screen, which ought to make it the main...
[image]

*Edit: Untested on a laptop [iMac classes as a laptop for this], I have a Mac Pro with 2 external screens*

*Edit 2: That probably doesn't help if you can't see the prefs...*

Comment: You'd be correct; It doesn't help if I can't see the system preferences. I can click on system preferences in the applications folder, but it always opens on the main screen....which I can't see.

Comment: There's a trick: **[Either]** to click on the top-left Apple icon, on the screen where you want the preferences to appear, and then select "System Preferences...". **[Otherwise]** move the TopBar to the second monitor (as explained above), then just hover on the DockBar in the monitor you want as your main one; this will make the "System Preferences..." (and any system notification) to appear on that monitor (yeah ...sorcery ‍♂️) – *from [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157260/notifications-on-dual-monitors-how-can-i-specify-which-monitor#comment471271_183163)*